# I am working on a thermometer and humidity why am i getting this error

Tags: arduino-uno

Arduino: 1.8.9 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

In file included from C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DHT-sensor-library-master\DHT_U.cpp:15:0:

C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DHT-sensor-library-master\DHT_U.h:36:29: fatal error: Adafruit_Sensor.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

This indicates your IDE is missing the "Adafruit Unified Sensor" library as outlined [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=471001.0).

To install it, select "Tools" -> "Manage Libraries" and search for "Adafruit Unified Sensor". You can install the library by selecting it and pressing "Install".